# gradle providedCompile for gwt-user/dev causes other jars to disappear from WAR

Tags: gwt, jar, gradle, war

I assemble WAR for GWT application through gradle.

When GWT is included like

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.5.1"
    compile "com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.5.1"
    ...
}
```

then I have gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar in resulting WAR file. They are not really needed and are big. If I **delete these jars from WAR** - application works well.

But when I try to assemble WAR without these jars inside using

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile "com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.5.1"
    providedCompile "com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.5.1"
    ...
}
```

then the application cannot start in tomcat saying

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
```

and other strange error messages.

How can I correctly exclude just gwt-user and gwt-dev jars from gradle build?

Comment: Looks like some other jars are missing from WAR too... I'll dig into it

Comment: Yep. (1) `providedCompile` instead of `compile` on gwt causes validation-api*.jar to disappear from WAR. (2) Missing validation-api causes application to fail. But why in the world (1) happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other jars that are listed in `compile` section did disappear from WAR too. It can be quickchecked (you may not assemble the whole war) with

```
gradle :dependencies
```

and checking `providedCompile` section. In my case it was `validation-api` as subdependency of gwt-user.

```
+--- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.5.1
|    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.json:json:20090211
+--- com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.5.1
|    \--- org.json:json:20090211
\--- javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
```

It is required by the app and its jar was removed resulting WAR.

To persist them, I had to write the following in build.gradle:

```
providedCompile ("com.google.gwt:gwt-user:$gwtVersion") {
    transitive = false;
}
providedCompile ("com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:$gwtVersion") {
    transitive = false;
}
```

and everything went ok.