# Vaadin dependencies missing in war file created by gradle

Tags: gradle, vaadin, war

I try to build a war file using gradle and the Vaadin gradle plugin.
In the artifact created the Vaadin server jar is missing.

All necessary Vaadin dependencies are included in my eclipse project created with gradle eclipseClasspath and eclipseProject

using `-info` when executing gradle war I see the server dependency in the classpath and the dependency resolution.

Here is the `gradle -v` output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation 23.21-b01)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

and here the vaadin gradle plugin configuration, I use the version 0.7

```
vaadin {
   version = versions.vVaadin
   manageDependencies = false
   manageRepositories = false
   widgetset = 'de.mdsts.besprechungstool.BesprechungsToolWidgetset'
   gwt.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx512M', '-Xss1024k']
   gwt.strict = false
   gwt.userAgent = 'ie8,ie9,ie10,gecko1_8,safari,opera'
}
```

This is the first time I use gradle so any help is welcome.

Update:
This was a problem with transitive dependencies. Thanks to Alex fro the link.

**gradle :dependencies** showed this:

```
    providedCompile - Additional compile classpath for libraries that should not be part of the WAR archive.
    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:7.1.13
    |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:7.1.13
    |    |    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared-deps:1.0.2
    |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.1.13
    |    |    +--- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:7.1.13 (*)'
```

and in the build file I used

```
providedCompile("com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:$versions.vVaadin") {
    transitive = true'
}
```

using **false** fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with Gradle+Vaadin. internet suggests that it may be related to providedCompile masking transitive dependencies:
[gradle providedCompile for gwt-user/dev causes other jars to disappear from WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807307/gradle-providedcompile-for-gwt-user-dev-causes-other-jars-to-disappear-from-war)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the hint.
Indeed this was a problem with transitive dependencies.